# Ckeck if WPF Prism dialog is already open

Tags: wpf, prism

Is there a way of checking whether a WPF Prism 7 Dialog is already open. This is one launched with the new Prism Dialog service. We are using a common window for several dialogs so cannot just check if the window is open, we need to know if this specific Dialog user control has already been shown.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. The provided [dialog service implementation](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/5ddd97b5c0a9169a081401a766d5448c6b29b4a9/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Services/Dialogs/DialogService.cs) basically just resolves and shows a window. It doesn't keep track of currently open dialogs.

If you are using the same window to display several kinds of dialogs, you will have to keep track of which dialogs are currently open yourself. You could for example implement a custom dialog service or an an extension method that stores some information about the dialog to be opened in some collection just before calling the `Show` method.